# How to get the full file path of an arbitrary ruby class?

Tags: ruby

eg:

```
class Base

    def self.inherited(subclass)
        puts "New subclass: #{subclass}"
        path_of_subclass = ????
    end
end
```

Then in another file/class, it extends Base.

```
class X < Base
          ....
end
```

How would I get the path to the rb file of that subclass from the super class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) method and parse it for the filename. `inherited` is always called from the file that is defining the class.

Consider the following:

a.rb:

```
require 'pp'
class Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    pp caller
  end
end
```

b.rb:

```
require './a.rb'

class Derived < Base
end
```

Let's run this:

```
$ruby b.rb
["b.rb:3"]
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, I think is just what I need! 

I did the following to get the file out of the caller array:

    splits = caller[0].split(":")
    caller_file = splits[0] + ":" + splits[1]
    puts 'caller_file=' + caller_file

Hmmm, doesn't format very well in these comments.

Comment: note that `caller` returns an array of basically a stack trace with the subclass being the first item in the array. (I misunderstood this the first time I tried to use it)

Comment: Also, a simpler way to parse caller for the filename: `caller.first[/^[^:]+/]`

Answer (score -2):

```
File.expand_path(subclass.to_s)
```

Edit: Sorry, I just realized the original way would not work if they aren't defined in the same file.

Comment: subclass.to_s gives you the name of the class. There isn't necessarily any relationship between the class name and the file name.